# What needs to be done before using connected mode and custome rules for SonarLint

Tags: java, sonarlint, sonarlint-eclipse

I'm using SonarLint for eclipse. I've successfully connected it to the SonarQube server. (when I deactivate a rule on the server, I can see that the issues that in sonarLint issues window disappear.) However, the custom rules I developed can't be found in the SonarLint issues.

The custom rules are already in use through Jenkins on the SonarQube server and they are activated already. And the sonarLint I use is 2.2.1.

So, is there something I should do to make custom rules come into effect, other than connect to the sonar server, and turn the rules on?

Comment: Which version of SonarQube are you using ?

Comment: I'm using SonarQube 5.6.1 and I'm using eclipse neon

Answer (score 1):

Support for Custom Rules was introduced in SonarLint for Eclipse v2.2.0 and (as of this writing) works only with SonarQube 6.0+ .

Compatibility with SonarQube 5.6 is planned for upcoming versions, you can track progress via ticket [MMF-465](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-465) .